# How to make image scroll inside div horizontally

Tags: php, html, css, image, scroll

I have some images I want them to be displayed horizontally and it should scroll horizontal if there's no more room for image in div rather then displaying vertically.

My code:
index.php

```
foreach(somecondition) { //getting images from the directory
     echo '
            <div class="images">
           
           
            <div class="Image"><img src="'.$saving.' " width="100" height="100" alt="Random image" class="img-responsive"  /></div>
        
            
            </div>
            
            ' ;
}
           }
```

style.css

```
.images {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.Image {
  width: 24.5%;
  background-color: #eee;
  float: none;
  height: 90%;
  margin: 0 0.25%;
  display: inline-block;
  zoom: 1;
}
```

Right now it displays the image vertically and there is no scroll either. How can I achieve a horizontal scroll?

Updated code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cardAli.css">


</head>
<body>
<?php
 require "navigationbar.php";
require "testing.php";



session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['userUsername'].$_SESSION['userId'];
/*$last_id = $_SESSION['last_id'];
$dirName =  $_SESSION['dir_name'];*/

$image = 'userPos/hemlata993';


function listFolderFiles($dir){



echo '<div class="my_class">';
    $ffs = scandir($dir);

    unset($ffs[array_search('.', $ffs, true)]);
    unset($ffs[array_search('..', $ffs, true)]);
    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1)
        return;
$column_count = 0;
echo '<div class="images">';
 
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
    
   
      $s = "'<li>'.$ff";
    
       
        $saving = "$dir/$ff";
      
        $string = "$saving";
        global $string_arr;
$string_arr = (explode("/",$string));


        $sav;
         $sav =  '<li>'.$ff;
       
         
         global $sa;
        $sa = "$ff";
      
     
        
  
   
       if(is_file($saving)) {

        
        
        echo '

       
        <div class="image">
       
       
        <img src="'.$saving.' " width="100" height="100" alt="Random image"   />
    
        
        </div>
        
        ' ;
       }


    
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
        
      
    
    }
    echo '<div>';

 
    require "testing.php";


    $username = $_SESSION['userUsername'].$_SESSION['userId'];
    
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `_desc` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `id` = '$string_arr[2]';";
    
    
    
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    
 
    
    
    if($resultCheck > 0) {
        echo '</br>';
    
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
           
            echo '<div class="grid">' . '<h2>' .  $row["_name"] . '</h2>' . '</div>';
           
            echo '<div class="grid2">' . '<p>' .  $row["_desc"] . '</p>' . '</div>';
            echo '<hr/>';
            // you can echo other info inside the grid
      
          
        }

    
       
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
listFolderFiles($image);










?>
    


</body>
</html>
```

If I do what people suggested in the answers it only display the first set of images only but not the second and also does not display any description or name after it as I have in my code if I follow what people suggested in answers. Could you please have a look at my code? I am not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try removing `float: none` in `Image` class.

Comment: @bertdida It's still the same

Comment: are you using bootstrap or some library?

Comment: What's up with the `foreach(somecondition)`? That's not how you loop in PHP.

Comment: Would   `overflow-x: scroll;` and `overflow-y: hidden;` on your `.Image` class not work?

Comment: You have a silly mistake : remove .images div from the `for loop` and add it before the `for loop`

Comment: @bertdida  Yes, I am using bootstrap, but I tried removing it and its still the same.

Comment: @AbhishekKamal I tried doing that it does show image then but does not show any desc or name I have in my code after it.

Comment: @iachi check my answer below.

Comment: In your updated code block, you have initialised some variables like `$s` and `$sav` but where you used both variables ? You writes `$s = "'<li>'.$ff";` but where is the closing tag of this **li**. You writes `<div class="images">` but where is the closing tag of this **div**. I have already answered your question but I am going to re-answer again according to your updated question.

Answer (score 0):

Here, try this

In your HTML, take the `<div class="images">` outside the loop

```
<div class="images">
      
     <?PHP 
        $images = "";
        foreach(somecondition) { //getting images from the directory
        $images .= '<div class="Image"><img src="'.$saving.' " width="100" height="100" alt="Random image" class="img-responsive"  /></div>' ;
    } 
        echo $images;

     ?>
</div>
```

And in your css

```
<style>
    .images {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .Image {
        width: 24.5%;
        background-color: #eee;
        float: none;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0 0.25%;
        display: inline-block;
        zoom: 1;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to display all images from your directory with vertical scroll.

The problem is with your `php` codes, you're not using [`foreach`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_foreach.asp) properly. You are also referencing `$saving` variable which doesn't exists — you need to use the current image in the `src` attribute to display it correctly.

Hopefully, the code below will help you push forward on what you're trying to achieve.

```php
<?php
// images from your directory
$images = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/150'
];
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    .images {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
        white-space: nowrap;
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        overflow-y: hidden;
    }

    .Image {
        width: 24.5%;
        background-color: #eee;
        float: none;
        height: 90%;
        margin: 0 0.25%;
        display: inline-block;
        zoom: 1;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div class="images">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) : ?>
            <div class="Image">
                <img src="<?= $image ?>" width="100" height="100" alt="Random image" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: $saving does exists.  $saving = "$dir/$ff"; in my code

Comment: It only display first loop of images and stop and does not display any code after image such as name and description

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this code in your localhost.
I have added CSS `flex` property and used https://placeholder.com/ to get images.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .images{
                width: 500px;
                height: 100px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                position: relative;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
                /* newly added css */
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                margin:-7px 0 0 -7px;
            }

            /* newly added css */
            .images > div{
                margin:7px 0 0 7px;

            }
            .Image{
                width: 24.5%;
                  background-color: #eee;
                  height: 90%;
                  margin: 0 0.25%;
                  float:none;
                  display: inline-block;
                  zoom: 1;
            }

        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php 
        $img = '';
        $img .= '<div class="images">';
        for ($i=25; $i <250 ; $i+= 5) { 
            $img .= '<div class="Imgage"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/'. $i . '"></div>';
        }
        $img .= '</div>';

        echo $img;

         ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Given below is the answer according to updated question -

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cardAli.css">
</head>
<body>

<?php
require "navigationbar.php";
require "testing.php";
$username = $_SESSION['userUsername'].$_SESSION['userId'];
$image = 'userPos/hemlata993';

function listFolderFiles($dir){
    // removing . and .. from scandir()
    $ffs = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('..', '.'));
    // prevent empty ordered elements
    if (count($ffs) < 1) return;

    $column_count = 0;
    echo '<div class="my_class">';
    echo '<div class="images">';
    foreach($ffs as $ff){
        $s = "'<li>'.$ff";
        $saving = "$dir/$ff";
        $string = "$saving";
        $string_arr = (explode("/",$string));
        $sav =  '<li>'.$ff;
        $sa = "$ff";

        if(is_file($saving)) {
        echo '<div class="image"><img src="'.$saving.' " width="100" height="100" alt="Random image"/></div>';
       }
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$ff)) listFolderFiles($dir.'/'.$ff);
    } // foreach
    echo '</div>';

    // Your sql code starts...
}
listFolderFiles($image);
?>
</body>
</html>
```